# how to implement jQuery Datepicker into Rails 5.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to implement jQuery Datepicker into my Rails 5.1.3 app, but I get this error message:

> ActionView::Template::Error at /users/2/absences/new File to import
>   not found or unreadable: jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker. Load paths:
>   /Users/acandael/Sites/absence_registrator/app/assets/config
>   /Users/acandael/Sites/absence_registrator/app/assets/images
>   /Users/acandael/Sites/absence_registrator/app/assets/javascripts
>   /Users/acandael/Sites/absence_registrator/app/assets/stylesheets

I have added the jquery-ui-rails gem to the Gemfile

Then I configured the app/assets/javascripts/application.js file:

```
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
```

and I also configured the app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss file:

```
@import "jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker";
```

finaly I configured the Datepicker in the view template:

```
<%= f.text_field :date, class: "form-control", id: "datepicker" %>

<script>
 $(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });
</script>
```

### Update

I made some progress by changing

```
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
```

to

```
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
```

in app/assets/javascripts/application.js

In app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

I changed

```
@import "jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker";
```

to

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
*/
```

but the Datepicker that appears is not styled.

So my question now is how implement css styling for the Datepicker

### Update

I fixed the styling issue by importing:

```
@import 'jquery-ui/datepicker.css';
```

into app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

I tried your approach and several others. They all error'd out or didn't show the JS control where they should.

Ultimately I used this gem instead, and followed their pretty simple instructions and success! Rail 5.0.6.
https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails